# Spring EL - if else condition

Tags: spring, spring-el

I am trying to form a Spring expression like below

```
<bean id="merchantPayment2-cronTrigger" class="uk.co.xxx.batch.merchantpayment2.CronTrigger">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="merchantPayment2-jobDetail" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="#{ ${merchantPaymntRptJob.useDB}== true ? (applicationConfigurationService.merchantPaymentCronExpression) : ${merchantPaymntRptJob.cronExpression} }"/>
</bean>
```

what I meant to do is if property merchantPaymntRptJob.useDB is true then take the value from db using service or use the value from property file.

The trouble is using applicationConfigurationService.merchantPaymentCronExpression 
I tried different combinations - adding $ , # or just () but doesn't work. Can you please help.

Comment: Try `systemProperties['merchantPaymntRptJob.useDB']`. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html

Comment: trouble is not with merchantPaymntRptJob.useDB but with other two expressions.

Comment: Oh... there is a construct to use other beans in SpEL `@applicationConfigurationService` - https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-bean-references

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. Below one is now working.

```
#{ (${merchantPaymntRptJob.useDB}== true) ?(@applicationConfigurationService).merchantPaymentCronExpression :'${merchantPaymntRptJob.cronExpression}'}
```